# How to count a number of elements in a set with subsequent natural numbers and why substracting the lowest number from the highest is wrong??

Tags: elementary-set-theory, natural-numbers

I just started learning math from 0 and looking for explanation

I have a set {18,...,32} and the task is to find its cardinality. I was thinking that substracting the lowest (18) from the highest (32) would give me the correct answer (15), but it gives me incorrect one (14). It's off by 1. I can't figure it out why is it so? It seems the correct formula is (max_number - min_number + 1).

Manually counting numbers seems that it's true, the answer is 15, but I can't figure out where does 1 go if I use substraction?

Comment: The difference tells us how many steps we need from the lower to the higher number. The number itself is not considered this way. This is the reason for the "$+1$"

Comment: Do you think that the set $\{18,19\}$ consists of a single number?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, thanks!

And indeed, 19 - 18 would give us 1, while the set has cardinality of 2. It still feels a bit counter-intuitive to me, I am not sure why? 

Thinking about it... Yeah, I understood substraction wrong. Substraction gives the difference between two numbers, and the difference does not equal to the number of members of a set. And I wrongly presumed, that it would equal.

Comment: If you drive along a road from mile marker $18$ to mile marker $32$, you will have driven $14$ miles, but you will have seen $15$ mile markers because there is one marker at each end of your drive.